# Batch refactor: rename class references in PHP source files

Tags: php, automated-refactoring

I'm trying to refactor a project; task is to rename `\Qualified\Class`, `use Qualified; ... Class ...` references to `use \Some\Other\Qualified\Ns; ... OtherClass ...`.

I must also replace said reference in PHPDocBlock annotations.

Tool must replace references in all php files in a specified folder, which don't follow a particular structure.

I'm looking through available tools, doesn't seem there's a lot of them. phpactor looks like it should do something of the sort, but I can't get a hang of how it's supposed to work:

```
phpactor --replace=Ns1\\Cl1 references:class Ns2\\Cl2

There are no file path candidates
```

Any hint on how I can achieve this? I have a ton of classes to move around and refactor...

Comment: Any IDE worth using should be able to do this without any issues.  Personally I use PHPStorm from JetBrains, Just right click => refactor any variable or class name.

Comment: @AlexBarker Thanks, I was looking for a way to do this CLI-way. But speaking of PHPStorm, is there any way to refactor with "Simplify FQN" enabled? (I mean, add `use Name\Space\Class` on top)? I am using the "move" option to refactor the namespace part (haven't found any other way) but it replaces the full path in every reference...

Comment: I think if you refactor the class name instead of the filename (or vice versa) it will do what you want.

Comment: How do I do that? If I Refactor->Rename the class name it will only let me change that - the name, not the namespace.

Comment: If you Refactor->Rename the class name, it should update the use references and annotations of that class in other classes as well as the classes filename.  If you do the same thing on the namespace, it should have similar effect on the path and usages.

Comment: I would suppose so, except that you can't rename the namespace. You can only move it. Or I'm not finding the right clicks.

Comment: You need to right-click on the node in the namespace; https://pasteboard.co/IBxLEAH.png

Comment: I see... my problem was that some classes are in the global NS and need to be moved... I can't rename the global ns, obviously :) For others, it works, except as you start consolidating, renaming namespaces becomes more and more tricky. For instance, if you have `NS1\A`, `NS1\B` and you want to move just `B` to `NS2\B` you will inadvertently also move A. So I really need a tool that refactors class FQNs.

Comment: And it would be a great bonus if it were scriptable; if you do this by hand and you screw up (which is very likely, as there are i.e. classes with the same name in different namespaces), you have to start over. Whereas, with a script, you just rollback and run it again.